# Extract IP address from /etc/hosts file with SED command

Tags: shell, sed

I would like to extract the IP v4 address only from  my /etc/hosts file with  shell sed command.

I managed to isolate those line with localhost at the end of the line   with the following command:

```sh
$ sed  -E '/localhost$/!d ' host_1 | sed -n 1p
```

which  gave me the following output :

*#       127.0.0.1       localhost*

How can I only extract the IP v4 address alone form the above result?

Answer (score 1):

The test data:

```
$ cat file
127.0.0.1 localhost
# 127.0.0.2 localhost
127 127.0.0.3 localhost
```

The sed:

```
$ sed -n  's/\(.*[^0-9]\|\)\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*/\2/p' file
```

The output:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

The sed with the `-E` switch:

```
$ sed -nE  's/(.*[^0-9]|)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\2/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -E '/localhost$/!d '   /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v :
```

Comment: Is there any way to use regex  associates with *sed* command to extract only that IPv4 Address alone

Comment: what do you mean? using only `sed` and nothing more? it's possible of course

Comment: I mean using  SED  with regex to extract the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command and it works fine.

```sh
$ sed  -E '/localhost$/!d' host_1 | sed -n 1p  |grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
```

output:   127.0.0.1

> Nonetheless I am still curious about  how can I substitute the grep  by a sed command.

Answer (score 0):

Late but you can try this :

```
sed  -E '/localhost$/!d ' host_1 | sed -n 1p | sed -r 's/\localhost//g'
```

The last part replaces the **grep** used by **4everLRG**

If you need to extract localhost IP from **/etc/hosts** make sure to replace *host_1* with */etc/hosts*